# problem with googlescholar link in classic style moderncv

Tags: moderncv, google-scholar

I have trouble including a link to google scholar in my CV. Specifically, the following does not compile:

```latex
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} % works with `casual' instead of `classic'
\name{Max}{Power}
\social[googlescholar]{XYZ}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

But it does compile when replacing `classic` with `casual`. Is this a bug? Does anybody have a quick workaround?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the end of the output of `pdflatex` (on ubuntu 22.04 with texlive 2021.20220204-1):

```
(./cv-test.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(./cv-test.out) (./cv-test.out)
! Undefined control sequence.
\Url Error ->\url used in a moving argument. 
                                             
l.8 \makecvtitle
```

And I just noticed that it *does* compile with `lualatex`!

Comment: It compiles fine with TL 2023. If you can include the error message, you may get solutions.

Comment: @mas thanks! I added the tail of the output of texlive (ubuntu 22.04 w/ texlive 2021). and I just noticed that it *does* compile with lualatex!

Comment: Why not upgrade to TL 2023? If you have not installed TL via ubuntu repos, you can try that. As a long time debian user, I always use TL directly rather than what is provided by the deb repos.

Comment: I *do* have texlive installed via ubuntu repositories. for now, using lualatex is the simpler workaround :-)

Comment: The  tail of the error message suggests that your document doesn't actually contain `\social[googlescholar]{XYZ}` but, rather, something with a `\Url` directive. Is this impression correct? If so, what's the actual argument of `\social`?

Comment: The document is exactly as I quoted it above.